# Login with Google using Ionic framework gives 404 on callback

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-oauth

I am trying to implement login with Google in an Ionic browser based app. These are the commands I ran to install and create my app:

```
ionic start tracker sidemenu
cd tracker
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
ionic platform add browser
```

When I click my login button, the Google auth comes up ok. However when the callback is called I get a 404:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    
http://localhost:8100/callback?code=xxxxxx
```

This [OAuth 2 Ionic example](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/using-oauth-2-0-service-ionicframework/) gave this code:

```
var clientId = 'xxxxxx-3rpu226qm-xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var scope = 'profile email';
var ref = window.open('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=' + clientId +
'&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8100/callback&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener&approval_prompt=force&response_type=code&access_type=offline',
  '_blank', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {
  console.log('listener event.url: ' + event.url);
  if ((event.url).startsWith("http://localhost:8100/callback")) {
    var requestToken = (event.url).split("code=")[1];
    console.log('request token from google: ' + requestToken);
    ref.close();
  }
});
```

Why isn't the eventListener catching the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a known issue of the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser that loadstart and loaderror events are not being fired in the browser.

Source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#browser-quirks-1

You might want to look at an other javascript library like hello.js for the browser case (https://adodson.com/hello.js/#hellojs). Or implement it yourself. Here you can find an example for how to do it for google oath2 yourself: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: Are there any known examples of trying to authenticate a user with google in order to access google docs/drive ?